# How can a Windows app read real time temperatures from a T.I. TMP117EVM module?

Tags: windows, sensors, texas-instruments

We don't have our hardware interface yet that reads the TMP117 sensor chip by I2C.

So, we'd like to read real time temperatures from the T.I. evaluation module TMP117EVM with a Windows .NET or Mac OS app.

And, T.I. says they don't have anything to support that kind of programming interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of the complex and time-consuming TI solution, I used the Adafruit solution, which worked great, and interfaced to two TMP117 chips and tiny eval boards also from Adafruit.

I made a .Net app talk to Arduino app that used Arduino IDE's TMP117 library that used I2C to talk to TMP117 to read temperature.

[Here is Adafruit guide](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-tmp117-high-accuracy-i2c-temperature-monitor?view=all)